# Can be saved into a variable one condition?

Tags: python, variables

It would be possible to store the condition itself in the variable, rather than the immediate return it, when to declare it?

Example:

```
a = 3
b = 5

x = (a == b)
print(x)

a = 5
print(x)
```

The return is

```
False
False
```

However, I expected to get

```
False
True
```

I'm just having fun with the magic of Python. I know it is possible using a function, but I wonder if it is possible using a variable.

Comment: You can use a lambda function: `x = lambda a, b: a == b` and then `x(3, 5)`

Comment: The reason you dont get the result you expected is because the condition stored in the variable `x` isn't updated with the new value stored in `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition is always evaluated immediately. If you want to evaluate it on demand, you could make it a function or a lambda expression:

```
x = lambda: a == b
print(x())
```

Also, you could probably do some black magic and make a class that evaluates the condition when it's printed:

```
class Condition:
  def __init__ (self, cond):
    self.cond = cond
  def __str__ (self):
    return str(self.cond())

x = Condition(lambda: a == b)
print(x)
```

This is only for educational purposes though, don't use it in production. Also note that it onl works in print statements - to make it work in `if` statements etc you would also have to override `__bool__` (python 3) or `__nonzero__` (python 2).

Answer (score 2):

You can get this kind of reactive pattern by using a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.a == self.b
```

Then:

```
>>> t = Test(a=3, b=5)
>>> t.x
False
>>> t.a = 5
>>> t.x
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that's called a function! :)

```
def x(a, b):
    return a == b
```

Comment: Oh, yes, I know, but I wonder if it would be possible in a variable.

Comment: not really, you can make a function which depends on a global state, and instead writing `print(x)` you could write `print(x())`, but it's ugly, and wouldn't be a pure function

Answer (score 1):

No. You need a function for that.

```
def test(param_1, param_2):
    return param_1 == param_2

a = 3
b = 5
print(test(a, b))
a = 3
print(test(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the magic to happen when you print x, override `__str__`.

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return str(a == b)
...
>>> x = X()
>>> print(x)
False
>>> a = 5
>>> print(x)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

make it a simple function:

```
def f(a,b):
    x= (a==b)
    print x
f(3,5)
f(5,5)
```

Additionally, if you are asking if you can store the condition in the variable, You have done that. That is why X holds a value of either true or false depending on the output of the function. if you want to use it with only a variable but not a function you will have to add `print(x)` after everytime you update either of the variables